# 2 ruby apps on one server with different Ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, redmine

I've got server with Linux Red Hat, Ruby 2.2 и Git Lab. Nginx + Passenger is running Git Lab on Ruby 2.2. I need to run Redmine 2.5.2 on Ruby version not higher than 2.1. No RVM installed yet. Please advce, is it possible to install second Ruby 2.0 on same server and make Redmine 2.5.2 work with it? Git Lab must be working too.  It's not possible to uninstall anything already installed... Please  help me with ths problem.

Comment: Are you utilising virtual machines or is it not an option?

Comment: RHEL is installed on virtual machine, but I don't think it matters, cause I need to run both GitLab and Redmine on one server

Comment: It is 100% possible to run two rails app with different ruby versions using nginx and passenger. For multiple ruby versions on your server you have to use rvm or rbenv. Try this for configuration. https://coderwall.com/p/x2_z4a/multiple-rubies-with-a-single-passenge

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just set the `passenger_ruby` directive for Redmine to Ruby 2.0.